# can NOTmake my footer stick AND provide a scroll bar for content

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I've googled and read  just about everything I can find on making a "sticky footer" but for some reason I just can NOT get it to work correctly. Here's my CSS code for the html/body div, main content div and my footer div:

```
body, html {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 0px;
height: 100%;
font-family: Cooper Black, Copperplate Gothic Bold, Britannic Bold, Garamond, Arial;
font-size: 1em;
color: #666666;
background-color: #EDF5FC;}

#main {
position: relative;
top: 380px;
width: 90%;
height:100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0px 5% -20px 5%;
z-index: 10;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
overflow:scroll;}

#footer {
clear:both;
position:fixed;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-top: -20px; /* negative value of footer height */
width:98%;
height:20px;
padding-top:3px;
background: #0E28B1;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: .7em;
font-weight:bold;
z-index:1;}
```

My Footer Div is outside my Main div (the main content of the site is inside the main div, then I close it and have the footer div.) I can get it to stick at the bottom by using fixed position and margin-bottom: 0, but then I get no scroll bar for my content.

This is not working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution that works for me! I found this website: http://boagworld.com/dev/fixed-footers-without-javascript/ and modified the code just a tiny bit so that my footer text is nicely centered both vertically and horizontally, and added my top of page height in the main (content) div. I guess this won't work correctly without the third "#Wrapper" div enclosing everything - so now here is my wrapper, main and footer css for those having the same problems:

```
#wrapper {
display: block; 
position: absolute; 
min-height: 100%; }

#main {
display: block;
top: 400px;
width: 90%; 
margin-bottom: 20px; }

#footer {
position: fixed; 
display: block; 
bottom: 0; 
height: 20px; 
background: #0E28B1;
width: 98%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
font-size: .7em;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: Cooper Black, Copperplate Gothic Bold, Britannic Bold, Garamond, Arial;
color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
padding-top:3px;}
```

I had to make the z-index in the footer 2 instead of 1 to keep the footer on top of the content text. But now it works. I had searched SO many websites (including this one) before I found this solution, so I hope this helps someone.